# Add JS Form Action

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an HTML form but I don't know much about JS, and I need help.

When the user fills in and clicks on the button, I would like a text to appear and in the middle of the text I could pull the values ​​that he put in the form.

Example:

**Name:** Luis
**Email:** luis@test.com

**Text after clicking send:**
Hello **Luis**. His email is: **luis@test.com**

Do you know how I can do this action? My HTML form is this:

```
<label class="label" for="name">Nome do Código</label>
<input class="field" type="text" placeholder="Digite o nome do código..." />
<label class="label" for="name">Linguagem</label>
<select class="field">
    <option value="code">CSS</option>
    <option value="code">JS</option>
    <option value="code">PHP</option>
    </select>
<label class="label" for="name">Como usar?</label>
<input class="field" type="text" placeholder="Explique como o código será usado..." />
<label class="label" for="name">Código</label>
<textarea class="field" placeholder="Cole o código aqui." /></textarea>
<button class="button" type="submit">Enviar sua mensagem</button>
```

Meu código atual:

````
<label for="nome">Título do Código</label>
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Digite o título do código...">

<label for="nome">Linguagem</label><label id="cor" for="cor">//Para colorir o texto.</label>
<select type="text" name="ling" id="ling">
    <option value="css">CSS</option>
    <option value="js">JS</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option></select>

<label for="como">Como usar?</label>
<input type="text" name="como" id="como" placeholder="Explique como o código será usado...">

<label for="code">Código</label>
<textarea rows="5" name="code" id="code" placeholder="Cole o código aqui."></textarea>

<button id="enviar" onclick="mostrarMensagem()"> GERAR MEU CODIGUINHO</button>

<label id="title" for="nome" >Copie o código abaixo:</label>

<pre id="mensagem"></pre>

<script>
  function mostrarMensagem() {

    const nome = document.getElementById('nome').value
    const ling = document.getElementById('ling').value
    const como = document.getElementById('como').value
    const code = document.getElementById('code').value

    const mensagem = document.getElementById('mensagem')

   mensagem.innerHTML = ("**" + nome +"**<br>```"+ ling +"<br>" + code +"``` <br></br> > **Como usar:** " + como)
  }
</script>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I imagine you don't want to submit the form but just a way to get the inputs from the user? If so, you can just add IDs to your inputs, use JavaScript to get the values when the button is clicked and put them in another tag. Here's an example, I'll try to make it simple:

```html
<label for="nome">Nome</label>
<input type="text" name="nome" id="name">

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">

<button id="enviar" onclick="mostrarMensagem()">Enviar</button>

<p id="mensagem"></p>

<script>
  function mostrarMensagem() {

    const nome = document.getElementById('name').value
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value

    const mensagem = document.getElementById('mensagem')

    mensagem.innerHTML = ("Olá " + nome + ". Seu email é: " + email)
  }
</script>
```

Feel free to ask anything. Also... Pode ser em português também se preferir.

Comment: Agora que vi que tu é BR HUAHUAHAUH

Comment: Salvou demais, muito obrigado!

Comment: Tamo junto meu bom, valeu!

Comment: Mano, funcionou perfeitamente, porém estou com um único b.o.

Fiz esse formulário pra galera gerar um texto formatado do discord com códigos, mas quando é código js, ele lê o código ao inves de gerar o texto dele.

Na tag <p> da mensagem, troquei para <pre> pra respeitar as quebras de linha.

Consegue me ajudar? Tem alguma forma de fazer com que o <pre> ignore a leitura do JS na mensagem gerada e mantenha o texto do código?

Deixei meu novo código (com base no seu) na edição da minha pergunta aqui.

Valeu!

Comment: Hum, curioso... Tá com cara de ser algo mais do discord que do JS em si e fica complicado de eu testar aqui. O código é executado apenas quando está na tag pré? Se sim, não é possível usar outro método para quebra de linha como a própria tag <br>?

Comment: Na verdade esse form está numa página do meu site mesmo. A ideia do form é gerar o texto formatado para postarem no discord (pra evitar bagunça). Sou web designer e trabalho com wordpress/elementor, mas usamos bastante códigos prontos. Tenho um curso e os alunos podem postar os códigos deles. A ideia é gerar o texto pré-formatado pra eles só copiarem e colarem no discord, pra manter o padrão. O link é esse: https://discla.clacriativo.com/codiguinhos/

Comment: Tentei adicionar o textarea para a mensagem gerada, funcionou na questão do JS, mas ele adiciona o <br> nas quebras de linha, o que estraga toda a pré-formatação gerada para o discord. (que seria com negritos, citação, bloco de código colorido e tal). Não sei se deu pra entender a ideia, se não, só entrar no link e testar. Bota um código CSS lá, copia o que for gerado e cola no chat do discord, tu vai ver que vai ficar formatado certinho. Tô quebrando a cabeça aqui kkkkkk

Comment: Perdão por não dar retorno antes, faltou tempo. Conseguiu algo?

Comment: Imagina, tranquilo. Ainda nada 

Answer (score 0):

I would add the `name` tag to your inputs and do something like this

```js
//app.js
app.post("/someForm", (req, res) => {
  const { email, name } = req.body;

  res.render("welcomeUser", { name: name, email: email });
})
```

```html
<!-- welcomeUser.ejs -->

<h4>Hello <%= name %>. His email is: <%= email %></h4>
```

There might be a better answer but this was the one that was coming to my mind

Comment: I think this could be a useful answer if looking for a server-side solution, but the question seems to be looking for a client-side solution (e.g. note that the question doesn't include anything server-side).